# Spring Kafka DefaultErrorHandler / FailedBatchProcessor commits offset even when auto commit is disabled

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have configured a `MessageListenerContainer`, using a `BatchMessageListener` and `DefaultErrorHandler` .

I never want to commit any record, because the (log compacted) topic is bootstrapped on each restart of the service. Therefore I set consumer properties `auto.offset.reset=earliest`, `group.id=null` and `enable.auto.commit=false`. Additionally I have set `defaultErrorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(false)` and `containerProperties.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL)`.

Having a batch of records where the processing of one record failed (because `BatchListenerFailedException` was thrown), the `DefaultErrorHandler` (superclass `FailedBatchProcessor`) kicks in. After back offs are exhausted and the failed record was skipped (see [SeekUtils.seekOrRecover](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2.8.x/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/SeekUtils.java#L190)), the `FailedBatchProcessor` still wants to commit offsets as seen in this code: [FailedBatchProcessor.seekOrRecover](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/2.8.x/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/FailedBatchProcessor.java#L192).

The commit fails because of the missing `group.id`. The processing of the remaining records stops and an exception is raised:

```
2023-06-15T14:54:38,935+0200 ERROR [custom-listener-id-topic-c-0-C-1] [KafkaMessageListenerContainer] Error handler threw an exception
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.
```

Why does `FailedBatchProcessor` does not check if auto commit is disabled? How can I prevent `FailedBatchProcessor` from committing offsets and just proceed with the remaining records?

I am using Spring Kafka 2.8.11.